# Show checkbox checked from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I'm using Laratrust package for ACL in my application. I'm trying to edit roles (assign permissions to role) using checkbox. And want get already assigned permission checkbox state checked from database.

Code in `RoleController.php`

```
    public function edit($id)
{
  $role = Role::where('id', $id)->with('permissions')->first();
  $permissions = Permission::all();
  return view('admin.manage.roles.edit')->withRole($role)->withPermissions($permissions);
}
```

Below is the code what I have tried:

```
@foreach($permissions as $permission)
 <div class="checkbox checkbox-styled">
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="{{$permission->id}}" 
    {{ $role->permissions->pluck('id') == $permission->id ? 'checked' : '' }}
    >
    <span>{{$permission->display_name}}  <em>({{$permission->description}})</em></span>
</label>
</div>
@endforeach
```

The code is throwing error
`Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int`

I had tried:

`{{ $role->permissions->id == $permission->id ? 'checked' : '' }}`

This throws error:

`Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance`

When I do `{{dd($role->permissions)}}`: The following output was given:

[image]

[image]

I would be very thankful if anyone could point-out mistake I'm doing here.

Comment: can you echo "<pre>"; print_r($role->permissions); and show

Comment: You're trying to check if a collection is equal to an int. `$role->permissions` is a collection. Try editing your post, while including your controller.

Comment: @Classified I've updated the question with code from my controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will not work because you are trying to compare array with a string, which is impossible. you can use php `in_array` function to check whether your permission exist for the current permission or not

I think you are trying to check all the permission which already exist for the specific roles. correct me if i am wrong.

Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="{{$permission->id}}" 
@if($role->permissions) @if(in_array($permission->id, $role->permissions->pluck('id')) checked @endif @endif>
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Vikash  with your code snippet. I'm getting error `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given`

Comment: Solved the problem by attaching `toArray()` method at the end of pluck method. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do is to check in collection using contain

`@if($role->permissions->contains($permission->id)) checked=checked @endif`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="{{$permission->id}}" 
{{ @if($role->permissions->contains($permission->id)) checked=checked @endif }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another short method.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="{{ $permission->id }}" 
{{ $role->permissions->contains($permission->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```